# Comparing value in dictionary with list (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, cs50

I working this CS50 problem set that tell us to match people DNA

This is my almost finished code:

```
import re, csv, sys

def main(argv):

    # Open csv file
    csv_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    people = csv.reader(csv_file)

    nucleotide = next(people)[1:]

    # Open dna sequences file
    txt_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
    dna_file = txt_file.read()

    str_repeat = {}
    str_list = find_STRrepeats(str_repeat, nucleotide, dna_file)
    
    match_dna(people, str_list)


def find_STRrepeats(str_list, nucleotide, dna):
    for STR in nucleotide:
        groups = re.findall(rf'(?:{STR})+', dna)
        if len(groups) == 0:
            str_list[STR] = 0
        else:
            total = max(len(i)/len(STR) for i in groups)
            str_list[STR] = int(total)
        
    return str_list


def match_dna(people, str_list):
    for row in people:
        # Get people name in people csv
        person = row[0]
        # Get all dna value of each people
        data = row[1:]
        
        # If all value in dict equal with all value in data, print the person
        if str_list.values() == data:
           print(person)
           sys.exit(0)
    
    print("No match")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

So, i have stuck on my `match_dna` function. I get confused on how to compare value in my dict: `str_list` with value in list: `people`.

```
str_list = {'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}

data = ['4', '1', '5']
```

Is there anything i should change in my code? or maybe a simple way to compare those two different structures? thx.

Comment: You can compare `str_list` and `data` by using `==` as you are already doing. Anyway, you should make sure the order of the fields in the both lists is the same, i.e., make sure you are not comparing an `AGATC` value with a `TATC` value.

Comment: Python supports structural equality on lists. However, data member's type and str_list's value types are different. Also, you can't rely on the return of `str_list.values()` in terms of the order, so it's better to sort both lists (data and str_list.values()) before comparison.

Comment: I guess the CSV file stores the values in a given order. I would use an `OrderedDict` for `str_list` to make sure I store the values in the dict in that very same order. Then you could safely do a `str_list.values() == data` comparison.

Comment: `data=row[1:]`, comment says 'Get all dna value of each people' is that correct as per your flow.

Comment: @rturrado it doesn't work, it always print no match. And where do i put `OrderedDict` in my code?

Comment: @sardok i'm sorry i don't quite understand. How do you mean sort? I have to sort those two structure first?

Comment: @Kevinkun You just need to add `from collections import OrderedDict` after your top import, and then define `str_list = OrderedDict()` at the beginning of `find_STRrepeats`.

Comment: @Kevinkun Another thing I would do for debugging is: 1) work with a CSV file of only 3 or 5 lines (3 or 5 data lists, I understand), and 2) print `str_list.values()` and `data` right before you do the comparison. That way you'll have some more insight as to what you are comparing and why it may fail.

Comment: @Kevinkun yes exactly, both sides should have the same structure & order. You can achieve what you need by `sorted(str_list.values()) == sorted(map(int, data))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_list = {'AGATC': 4, 'AATG': 1, 'TATC': 5}

data = ['4', '1', '5']

for data_item in data:

    for key,values in str_list.items():
    
        # list data '4','1','5' are in string 
        # and dictonery value 4,1,5 are in integer form
        # hence you need to compare the same data type 
    
        if values == int(data_item):
            print(key)
```

In your second snipped provided by you. List data i.e, "data" '4','1','5' is in the string and dictionary value i.e, "str_list" 4,1,5 are in integer form hence you need to compare the same data type by converting list data to an integer. You can view the above code by me for your reference.